# Premium rank when user subscribe (strip cashier) and remove when expire

Tags: laravel

I just added Laravel Cashier (Stripe) on my application, so I have the 2 tables subscriptions / subscriptions_items.
I also have a Ranks table with all my roles, administrator, moderator, premium, premium+, user...

When a user subscribes to the premium, I have a line that is added in the 2 subcriptions tables, to check that a subscription is in progress I have this method for example: user->subscribedToPrice()

The problem is that I don't want to use this method to check that a member is premium, I would like to have in his User table the rank_id with the id of the premium rank.
I could add the modification for the current user when buying the premium, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution since I have to manage the expiration.

A premium rank expires after 30 days and a premium+ rank is for life.

I can't use only the cashier method to check that it is premium because I have information like icons that are needed in the ranks table, so the premium user must be linked to a rank and not only to a subscription stripe.

So my question is, how to link stripe with laravel cashier and subscriptions to my database roles with expiration.

Here is the User table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();

            $table->foreignUuid('rank_id')->constrained('ranks');

            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('profile_visibility')->default(\App\Models\User::PROFILE_PUBLIC);
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('last_seen_feed')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
            $table->timestamp('last_seen_comments')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The Rank table:

```
Schema::create('ranks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();

            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('icon');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('price')->nullable();
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('staff')->default(0);
            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('strength');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The user relationship to rank:

```
public function rank()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Rank' );
    }
```

The Rank relationship to user:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
    }
```

The method that adds a subscription:

```
 public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();

        $priceId = $request->priceId;
        return $request->user()
            ->newSubscription('default', $priceId)
            ->allowPromotionCodes()
            ->checkout([
                'mode' => 'subscription',
                'success_url' => route('shop.checkout-success') . '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                'cancel_url' => route('index'),
            ]);
    }
```

Success page

```
public function success(Request $request)
    {
        $session = Session::retrieve($request->get('session_id'));
        $customer = Customer::retrieve($session->customer);
        $user = User::where('email', $customer->email)->first();

        $user->update(['rank_id' => RankHelper::getIdByName('Premium')]);

        return view('shop.success');
    }
```

I don't add the subscriptions tables, they are the default ones in laravel cashier.

Comment: I could add during the subscription, the rank_id for the current user, which would become premium. Then I add a middleware that checks if the user is premium & that his subscription is still running, if it is the case NEXT, if not I'll change the rank_id of the user to classic user. it seems a bit "heavy" to check each time though, I wait for your ideas to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd create either a job or a command which iterates through all current users and updates their rank according to what it should be. This job could be triggered when a payment is processed as well.

You can create a job with artisan, for example `php artisan make:job ProcessRanks` which will create a file called `app/Jobs/ProcessRanks.php`. This file will have a `handle()` function.  The `handle` function should contain the actual code.

In `app/Console/Kernel.php` you should be able to use something like `$schedule->job(new ProcessRanks)->twiceDaily();` in the `schedule()` function.

Comment: I never wanted to use the Job for that, I feel like it's very expensive, you have to have something running non-stop to make sure you have an up-to-date application. How often would you run the job to check if a rank is still not expired?

Comment: Expensive in what way? CPU cycles? Money? When looking at the situation you described (a subscription being valid for 30 days) I'd expect running it once a day to expire the subscriptions would be enough. However, that means that some users might get up to 23 hours 59 minutes "for free", and I don't know if that is an acceptable situation for you. However, it's already entirely plausible to run the job every hour, or even every 5 minutes.

Comment: So I'll do it like this, checking every 12 hours. Can you give me some guidance on how to do that? Make a Job that checks for expiration and then a task scheduling to run it every 12 hours?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that information :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going to explore it all

Comment: one last question, I made the Jobs, I added it in the Kernel (to test every minute), how do I make it run? usually I use queue:work but I don't have the impression that it's valid for this.

Comment: You can use `schedule:run` (which finishes) or `schedule:work` (which calls `schedule:run` every minute).

Comment: The jobs works great, but last little problem, when I have to put the user in premium once the payment is over. I tried with the success page, but I saw that I could reopen this page 1 week later and it puts me back to premium, would you have an idea of when I can put the user in premium? with a stripe webhooks?

Comment: I would just re-run the job instead of setting a user to premium. Perhaps specific to the one user, but the "thank you" page shouldn't just grant premium to every user visiting it.

Comment: I added in my first post the success method, maybe I should check, is the subscription in progress (just made the payment, yes), and in this case I pass premium. If the subscription is expired, it will not be able to access it.